# Installing Capistrano with a specific config dir

Tags: symfony, capistrano3

I have a Symfony2 application that I would like to deploy using Capistrano3. Performing `cap install` creates a `config` directory in the projectroot. To keep my project clean, I would like it to install the config dir into something like `app\config\capistrano`. Is this possible? I cannot find any hints in the documentations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the anwser in a [pull request on Github](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/pull/684).

Enter the following two lines to your `Capfile`, before `capistrano\setup` beign called.

`set :deploy_config_path, 'app/config/deploy.rb'
set :stage_config_path, 'app/config/deploy'`
`

It is implemented in the `3.1.x` branch

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `Capfile` and change the path to the config file. This should be enough.

Comment: well, the thing is, in the `Capfile` for capistrano3 there is no path to the config file anymore, and I can't find a description of all possible options and/or the syntax of the `Capfile` in capistrano3